# SQL Insert Data into TempTable by OUTPUT for not inserted data

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, insert-into

i have to insert data to one transaction table from temp table and need push the inserted primary id and other data to other temp table.

Please refer my code below

```
INSERT INTO Marks
    (subject, marks, studNm)
OUTPUT inserted.markid, tempdata.StdId INTO @tbl_new_school(markid, StdId)
SELECT
    tempdata.subject, 
    tempdata.marks,
    tempdata.studNm
FROM 
    @Temp as tempdata
WHERE 
    temp.markid != 0
```

am not able push the schoolId in the output. it is returning `tempdata.StdId cannot be bound`

Since each record in the temp table will have different STDid. i want to insert the respective inserted pk along with the STDId into temp table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Comment: am using SQL Server